# Transaction monitoring for deposits?

Tags: ether, web3js, ethereumjs

How do I monitor deposits for the account on ethereum? I saw some APIs that do this and I have tried to do the same on js web3 with filter but without any luck. What I would need is to get all the past transactions for specific address, maybe from the specified hash or just from the beginning if that is not possible.

Answer (score 4):

I've successfully used the EtherScan API's to pull down entire transaction lists for a given Ethereum address (or by repeatedly calling for a list of addresses). I even released some source code (C++) for doing this pretty easily from the command line: http://ethslurp.com. My stuff doesn't account for contract initiated calls, though.

Comment: Update to this comment: still working on it at http://quickblocks.io

Answer (score 1):

go-ethereum does not provide anything for this and developers are reclutant to implement. There is a closed bug regarding the issue.

If you want to get events of deposit create your wallets as smart contract and use filter event API.

Example:

https://github.com/websauna/websauna.wallet/blob/master/websauna/wallet/ethereum/contracts/wallet2.0.sol